# React how to create a component to save the history navigation path

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm studing react and I have just create the  item in order to print the history path of the user.
Here is the code:

```
return (
<div className="container">
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <Nav
          activeKey="/home"
          className="history-path"             
        >
          <div>you are here:</div>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/home" onSelect={() => history.push("/home", { from: "2" })}>Home</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <span>/</span>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/labour_desc" onSelect={() => history.push("/labour_desc", { from: "2" })} disabled>Description</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
</div>
)
```

For now, i'm copying and pasting the Nav with the add of the new link everytime.
For example, in the next page the Nav will be:

```
        <Nav
          activeKey="/home"
          className="history-path"             
        >
          <div>you are here:</div>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/home" onSelect={() => history.push("/home", { from: "2" })}>Home</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <span>/</span>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/labour_desc" onSelect={() => 
history.push("/labour_desc", { from: "2" })} disabled>Description</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
<span>/</span>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/new_desc" onSelect={() => 
              history.push("/new_desc", { from: "CreateDescription" })} 
              disabled>Create Description</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
```

I don't know how to create the component in order to pass just the new Nav.Item.
Any help?

Comment: hmmm.... can you elaborate more precisely. And update the question. I'm not able to understand what are you copy pasting and why

Comment: Sorry @ReyYoung, I'm doing right now

Comment: No need to be sorry. It's cool.

Comment: @ReyYoung I've modified the question, I hope that now would be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, from your question you want a component which contains some navigation links by default but that component should also be responsible to add new links for different page or component.

*Array of object containing the info about our route*

```
const defaultNavigations = [
  { name: 'Home', route: '/home', extraHistoryParams: { from: 2 } },
  {
    name: 'Description',
    route: '/labour_desc',
    extraHistoryParams: { from: 2 },
  },
];
```

*Component that creates navigation depending upon the navigations object*

```js
const Navigation = ({ additionalNavigations = [] }) => {
  /*
   * You will always get you default navigation if you don't have any additional
   * navigation send as a prop.
   *
   * We are merging our default navigation plus the new navigations you want
   */
  const allNavigations = [...defaultNavigations, ...additionalNavigations];
  // your can get your activekey from history.params

  return (
    <Nav activeKey='/home' className='history-path'>
      <div>you are here:</div>
      {allNavigations.map(({ name, route, extraHistoryParams = {} }) => (
        <Nav.Item key={name}>
          <Nav.Link
            href={route}
            onSelect={() => history.push(route, extraHistoryParams)}
          >
            Home
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      ))}
    </Nav>
  );
};
```

*Implementation of above Navigation component*
**a component which only needs default links**

```js
const BasicComponentWithDefaultNavigation = () => {
  return <Navigation />;
};
```

Now, the component which needs one additional route or link. You can add more routes.

```js
// This should have the format of the default navigation where extraHistoryParams is
// not required as this is optional because we have used default empty object in Navigation component
const newNavigation = [
  { name: 'Desc', route: '/desc', extraHistoryParams: { from: 'Create_Description' } },
];
const ComponentWithAdditionalNavigation = () => {
  return <Navgiation additionalNavigations={newNavigation} />;
};
```